# Scala Pairs: how to count the number of the ocurrences in the value (list of numbers)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a RDD[(Int, ListBuffer[Byte])] and I like to perform a "wordcount" but for each number in the List. 
For instance, the RDD is:

```
(31000,ListBuffer(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1))
(21010,ListBuffer(0, 0, 0))
(23000,ListBuffer(1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
(01000,ListBuffer(1, 1))
(34000,ListBuffer(0))
```

And I want to get this:

```
(31000,(0,2),(1,7)) // this could be a Map[0=>2, 1=>7]
(21010,(0,3))
(23000,(1,5))
(01000,(1,2))
(34000,(0,3))
```

Any guidance? Thank you in advance

Edit: someone suggested my question was duplicated, but the thing is the suggested post was about only a List, but I wanted to apply on a Pair (Int, List).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most idiomatic way to get a histogram of values in a Scala collection is to use `groupBy` followed by a map that takes the size of each resulting group:

```
scala> import collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import collection.mutable.ListBuffer

scala> val values = ListBuffer(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)
values: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int] = ListBuffer(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)

scala> values.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 7, 0 -> 2)
```

In your case that part is completely independent from the Spark part—you just happen to be performing this operation on values in an RDD, but the complete solution would look like this:

```
scala> val counts = myRdd.mapValues(_.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size))
counts: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int])] = MapPartitionsRDD[1] at mapValues at <console>:26

scala> counts.foreach(println)
(1000,Map(1 -> 2))
(21010,Map(0 -> 3))
(23000,Map(1 -> 5))
(34000,Map(0 -> 1))
(31000,Map(1 -> 7, 0 -> 2))
```

It's worth noting that the `mapValues` on Scala collections is lazy, which means that every time you use the maps in the RDD the values will be recomputed. This is probably fine, but if you're concerned, you can replace it with something like this:

```
values.groupBy(identity).map { case (k, v) => k -> v.size }
```

…which will return a strictly-evaluated map.